# getusermedia not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, getusermedia

getusermedia is not working in firefox but works in chrome and IE. I have the latest firefox 44.0.1. From what I read online it seems that firefox does not support this anymore and I need to use prefixes?

Comment: Got any code to go with that claim? The old browser-specific `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` (Firefox) and `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` (Chrome) are still there as they always have been, so no breaking change has happened there. Check your code. That said, the modern version shown in answer is better.

Answer (score 8):

In all browsers the right thing to use now is [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

The API underlying that has a better, modern design that uses Promises:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) { ... })
.catch(function(error) { ... })
```

Old [`navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is obsolete; Current browsers all support `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

To support very old browsers, you can still use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, but just along with the [adapter.js polyfill](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter):

```
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Trying to fix some older code however when I do alert(navigator.mediaDevices) in Firefox, it alerts "undefined".

Answer (score 5):

I want to post a comment but I do not have enough points. So I have to provide an answer here.

I just had a similar problem and everything works well in chrome, but firefox just give me an internal error. It turns out I cannot let two applications use one device. I closed the chrome, and then firefox works fine.